# Groovy SwingBuilder : changing size and/or font of tabs (in jTabbedpane)

Tags: groovy, jtabbedpane, swingbuilder

I can't find any information on how to change the tabs size or the font of the names labels (on color, etc)

Regards,
Michel

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that i guess your looking for [Practically Groovy(Part-2)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg11179/index.html). However in this link, you can scroll down to find the heading called "**Adding a TabbedPane to Gwitter**" Which does the good job of explaining how to create and handle the TabbedPane in Groovy.

Let me know if i have answered your question.

Comment: thanks for the links, Ant's; they will definitely help me, although not for this particular problem. I think I didn't expose the problem clearly enough; will repost it because I can't properly format in comment.

Comment: reposted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483261/groovy-swingbuilder-controlling-the-style-of-the-tabs-titles-in-jtabbedpane ; hope my question is clearer/more specific now.